# Recommended JMX plugin for Nagios?

Tags: nagios

There are several Nagios JMX plugins out there, according to the Nagios plugin registry and Google. **Any recommendations on one JMX nagios service check over the others?** The few I glanced at briefly didn't seem to be under active maintenance...

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Please have a look a [jmx4perl](http://www.jmx4perl.org/). It is acvtively maintained and continously improved (version 0.70 with multi checks is close to release, milestone 4 is already available).

Some unique features of jmx4perl (and check_jmx4perl) compared to the other Nagios JMX Plugins:

- No local java installation required on the Nagios Host (pure HTTP/Rest communication)
- Bulk requests (multiple JMX request within a single HTTP Request)
- Fine granular security policy possible
- Relative and incremental checks supported

You can find information about jmx4perl and some blog posts about it the [jmx4perl website](http://www.jmx4perl.org/).

(of course this info is a bit biased as I'm the author of jmx4perl ;-)